How to use AppleScript to insert 4 images into Keynote slide placeholders
I'm using AppleScript to make a photo album from a list of photos in a folder.
I'm stuck with inserting the folder's images into a slide.
The slide has 4 image placeholders, and the folder has 4 images, so it should place one image in each placeholder.
This is the code I'm using:
tell newSlide
    -- Iterate through all images in the slide
    repeat with i from 1 to 4
        -- Set the image for the current image placeholder
        set (image item i of newSlide) to (item photoIndex of locationPhotos as alias)
    end repeat
end tell


"newSlide" is a variable which points to my slide.
"photoIndex" is the index number of the file in the folder.
"locationPhotos" is a list of every file in the folder.
I'm getting this error:
Keynote got an error: Can’t make slide 8 of document id "73642C30-3D4A-4F2E-B3D7-BA0B8CA7B4DA" into type integer.
"Slide 8" is the same as the variable newSlide.
I also tried this:
tell newSlide
    -- Iterate through all images in the slide
    repeat with i from 1 to 4
        -- Set the image for the current image placeholder
        set thePlaceholderTag to "Foto" & i
        set targetImage to image placeholder(thePlaceholderTag)
        set image of targetImage to (item photoIndex of locationPhotos as alias)
    end repeat
end tell

And this gives me this error:
Expected end of line, etc. but found identifier.
This refers to the thePlaceholderTag variable in the line set targetImage to image placeholder(thePlaceholderTag)

It looks like I cannot get to refer to each image on the slide (there are no other images on the slide).
The placeholders have tags, but I don't now how to refer to them either.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

I think you have to use the make command, eg make new image with properties {file:thisImageFile}. I got that line from iworkautomation. There are a lot of limitations in scripting keynote (or any of the iwork apps) and unfortunately, the site doesn't often mention what you can't do so I take it as implicit that if I don't see an issue addressed, then it isn't addressable.

Thanks a lot, @Mockman! I found the placeholder management in the next page of that website: [https://iworkautomation.com/keynote/image-placeholder.html], but the code isn't working, even when I run exactly the same code. The error I get is "Can’t set file name of {«class imag», 1} to alias XXXXXX"

Two points: My observation has been that when your error message includes the word 'class' within chevrons, it means that whatever you intended to be there is not being recognised by the script when you run it. In essence, it is likely telling you that it doesn't know what you mean and therefore, it can't set the name of whatever it is to whatever name. Second, I think in this instance, you must use only the file's name, not its entire path. In the linked example, use "Saturn.jpg".

Programmatic is always better but if that doesn't work or is not supported, you can also drive the UI. Is the place holder an image that can be replaced with another image? I ask because if that's the case, the image place holder can be replaced by triggering the menu actions and setting the desired image by driving it via UI like how you would do it manually except by scripting those manual user interactions.
